# How do you create a 5-way contingency table using gt() in R?

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I have a stratified table from a 5-dimensional contingency table that I'm trying to format using the gt table object. Here's the code I used to create the contingency table:

```
tab<- table(nba$zoneBasic, nba$close_def_dist, nba$touch_time, nba$period, od=nba$off_dribble, 
dnn=c('Zone','Closest Defender Distance','Touch Time','Quarter','Off Dribble'))
```

And here's an example of one of the stratified tables:

[image]

According to the `tbl_strata()` documentation, it only takes a data frame or survey object. So, I convert the table to a data frame and this is the output:

[image]

Here's the code I used to format my table:

```
tab <- data.frame(tab)
tab.test <- tab %>%
  tbl_strata(
      strata = Touch.Time,Quarter,Off.Dribble,
      .tbl_fun =
        ~ .x %>%
        tbl_cross(Zone, Closest.Defender.Distance,margin=NULL)
    )
```

However, I'm not getting the correct output that I want. This is what the code is producing:

[image]

How do I use `gt()` to properly format my 5-way contingency table?

Comment: Use `dput(head(data))` , not pictures of data, to share data.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it's difficult to help you out. You can try making this change: `strata = c(Touch.Time,Quarter,Off.Dribble,)`